# Error conecting to my relay

Tags: relays, android

I'm running a relay in my computer. Using orfox I set it as Entrance Node, but it shows 
WARN:  Remote server sent bogus reason code 65022
I couldn't find this error in any site.
Is there something wrong with my relay?

Comment: It would certainly seem that one of the relays in the circuit sent a bogus reason, although it may not be yours, see: [`5.4. Tearing down circuits`](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n1123). So it could be your relay, or another relay along the circuit. If it happens to you for *all* circuits, it's probably your relay but we'd need more information to say for certain.

Comment: It's probably my relay. Because qhen I don't set a especific entry relay in orfox, it works.My torrc below
GeoIPFile C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Tor\tor-win32-0.2.9.9\Data#\Torgeoip
GeoIPv6File C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Tor\tor-win32-0.2.9.9\Data#\Tor\geoip6
ORPort 4443
DirPort 9990
#ORPort 127.0.0.1:8880
Exitpolicy reject *:*
#AccountingMax 10 GB
#AccountingStart day 00:00
#RelayBandwidthRate 500 KBytes
#RelayBandwidthBurst 1 MBytes
MaxMemInQueues 2048 MBytes
#Log debug file C:\Users\Rodrigo\Documents\Tor\tor-win32-0.2.9.9\Data\Tor\log.txt
P.S. Its a windows 7
tor-win32-0.2.9.9

Answer (score 1):

I think, actually, this is a bug in the client not the relay.

The circuit *is* failing *but* the error message is possibly a problem in the client, my reasoning is that the spec states:

> The payload of a RELAY_TRUNCATED or DESTROY cell contains a single octet.

Since an octet is 1 byte and 65022 > 255, this value can't be carried in a valid cell so it must be local to the client.

I think what you're seeing is this: [#20307](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/20307), essentially it's taking a signed integer and converting it to an unsigned short and your control port gets that bogus reason code. It's a bug in Tor, it should (?) be patched but it may be that Orbot hasn't applied and pushed the patched version yet.

Comment: Could it be because I'm not a guard node?